# Moving good/answered questions to different SE site

Tags: discussion, support, questions, migration

This question: [Hooked keyboard duplicating input (c# / xna)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201037/hooked-keyboard-duplicating-input-c-xna) has a very good accepted answer, which provides a better solution than one generally given online when searching.

Should it be moved to gamedev.stackexchange.com since it's a better fit and people might be more likely to come across it? Or should it not be moved because, although the OP came looking for a solution because of doing game development in [xna](/questions/tagged/xna) the problem and solution isn't related to game development directly.

Comment: I don't think this should be migrated at all. It's on-topic for Stack Overflow, and that's where I'd go to look for the answer. (That, of course, raises the question of what Game Dev is for... I don't know the answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the question is *clearly off topic* for the current site then it should be either migrated or closed. Only migrate if it's a) a good question and b) clearly on topic for the target site.

An example would be a question about iPhones on Super User. This is off-topic there and should be migrated to the Apple site.

Where the the question is *on topic* for the current site then it should remain where it is if it has an accepted answer. It serves no one to have the question migrated. You should *consider* migration if it has no answers or not many good answers.

Game Development is a good example as is a question about a Mac on Super User - it's on topic there but might get better answers on the Apple site.

So to answer this specific question - unless the OP requests it the question **should not** be migrated.